# How do I get access to AssetDetails (Assets Pallet) info from a Custom Pallet?

Tags: pallet, loose-coupling

I'm writing a custom pallet that uses AssetsPallet. The idea is to create a call/function that can be called only by the creator of an Asset/Token. I know I need that info from the following struct of Assets pallet:

```rs
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, Eq, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, MaxEncodedLen, TypeInfo)]
pub struct AssetDetails<Balance, AccountId, DepositBalance> {
    /// Can change `owner`, `issuer`, `freezer` and `admin` accounts.
    pub(super) owner: AccountId,
    /// Can mint tokens.
    pub(super) issuer: AccountId,
    /// Can thaw tokens, force transfers and burn tokens from any account.
    pub(super) admin: AccountId,
    /// Can freeze tokens.
    pub(super) freezer: AccountId,
    /// The total supply across all accounts.
    pub(super) supply: Balance,
    /// The balance deposited for this asset. This pays for the data stored here.
    pub(super) deposit: DepositBalance,
    /// The ED for virtual accounts.
    pub(super) min_balance: Balance,
    /// If `true`, then any account with this asset is given a provider reference. Otherwise, it
    /// requires a consumer reference.
    pub(super) is_sufficient: bool,
    /// The total number of accounts.
    pub(super) accounts: u32,
    /// The total number of accounts for which we have placed a self-sufficient reference.
    pub(super) sufficients: u32,
    /// The total number of approvals.
    pub(super) approvals: u32,
    /// The status of the asset
    pub(super) status: AssetStatus,
}
```

That is Stored in the following storage when created:

```rs
#[pallet::storage]
/// Details of an asset.
pub(super) type Asset<T: Config<I>, I: 'static = ()> = StorageMap<
    _,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    T::AssetId,
    AssetDetails<T::Balance, T::AccountId, DepositBalanceOf<T, I>>,
>;
```

I know this is related to the topic of loose coupling, but the examples I found use a frame_support trait as the link. So I'm not getting how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The idea is to create a call/function that can be called only by the creator of an Asset/Token.

Use this function to get the owner.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ae49625b5f7a4fa267082f8d415ea4f66ac02423/frame/assets/src/impl_fungibles.rs#L240-L242

Import the `frame_support::traits::fungibles::roles::Inspect`.

```rs
// Your pallet

use frame_support::traits::fungibles::roles::Inspect;

pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
  type Inspector: Inspect;
}

impl<T: Config> for Pallet<T> {
  fn is_owner/creator_of(who: &T::AccountId, asset_id: AssetId) -> bool {
    T::Inspector::owner(asset_id).map(|owner| owner == who).unwrap_or_default()
  }
}
```